# How can I convert a set of types and no. of instances into a list of all those instances in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I've looked around for guidance on this, but am a bit inexperienced so may have missed something obvious - sorry!

I'm hoping to be able to convert a set of types and no. of instances into a list of those instances in a way that is dynamic so that I can update the number of instances for example and the list would update (filling out new rows).

```
Type 1  |   0
Type 2  |   3
Type 3  |   2
Type 4  |   1
```

would return

```
Project 1   |  Type 2
Project 2   |  Type 2
Project 3   |  Type 2
Project 4   |  Type 3
Project 5   |  Type 3
Project 6   |  Type 4
```

If it's possible without VBA that would be brilliant.

Ideally it wouldn't be returned as an array - although it's not a problem if it does (especially if that's simpler)

I'm thinking there would be some function defined in VBA that returns an array an can sit over 100 rows and populate as the number of instances changed?

It needs to be able to manage when the no. of instances changes e.g. Type 4 has 10 instances and Type 2 has no instances

Hope that's clear, thanks very much for the help!

Comment: What have you tried ? Additionnally, I have noticed that in all your questions you never show any sign of effort of your own on the question. You will most likely be asked that question over and over without getting much help at all. Show that you have at least tried. As for the question, I'm pretty sure you can't do this in pure Excel formulas, you will have to use VBA.

Comment: It's also not clear where the count of the types turns into Project 1, Project 2, etc. But as @AlexandreP.Levasseur says, show us what you have tried in VBA and where you are stuck. That will help you and help us to help you more!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in Excel without VBA by using a helper column that contains some intermediate result. The following screenshot shows how that works:

[image: Screenshot of Excel, with the result in columns F and G, starting at row 2]

This is a screenshot of Excel, with the `D` as the intermediate column, and the desired result in columns `F` and `G`, starting at row `2`

Row `1` contains starting values to bootstrap your formulas. Cells in column `D` are used as a counter. Whenever it hits zero, its new value is read from cells in column `B`. The countdown formula in cell `D2`, for example, is

```
=IF(D1=0,INDIRECT("B"&(G1+2))-1,D1-1)
```

and is similar for all the cells in that column, with the row index adjusted automatically.

The cells in column `G` keep track of the current Type numer, increasing with `1` whenever the cell in column `D` hits `0`. The formula for cell `G2`, for example, is

```
=IF(D1=0,G1+1,G1)
```

This does what you are looking for... almost. There is a snag if a cell in column `B` has the value of `0`. In that case, you need to skip to the next non-zero cell. This can be done, and the whole example can be cleaned up somewhat as well. However, I did not want to spend too much effort on this until you have actually shown some response to this answer, proving that you are interested in learning some more advanced Excel formulas yourself.